# puppeteer event error handler don't go to catch block

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I'm creating a web scraping with puppeteer(nodejs), in some specific part of the web scraping i'm listening an event that is fired when the browser launch an dialog box with a message. on when this event is launched, i throw an exception, but this exception make the main process exit, and doesn't go to catch(err)

Example:

```
let page = null

const login = async () => {
  //Event listening
  page.on('dialog', async dialog => {
    throw new Error('login_error')
  }

async function processWebScraping () {
  try{   
     page = // Initialize puppeteer page
     await login() 
     [...]
  } catch(e){
     // the Error doen't come here, i got an uncaughtException 
     console.log(e) 
  }
```

someone know how can I get this error and handdle it?

Answer (score 4):

Try wrapping your listener in a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) instead. Doing so will allow to call `.then()` to resolve it and `.catch()` to catch an error. In your example it will look like this

```
const login = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  page.on('dialog', dialog => {
    reject(new Error('login_error'));
  });
});

function processWebScraping() {
  // page initialization

  login().then(() => {
    console.log('No error here');
  }).catch(err => {
    // Handle the error
    console.error(err);
  });
}
```